# Android studio 2.3.3 Logcat screen out from main frame not set back

Tags: android-studio, window, android-logcat

[image]

want to set back to the bottom menu or in Android monitor pane

Answer (score 0):

solved, by clicking the specific area of Logcat label and hold+drag to desire location

[image]